# Slide fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Задача реализовать активити в котором при нажатии на кнопку будут пролистыватся фрагменты.

activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;    
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class LearnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
            // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
            // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
            // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentLearnActivity.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class FragmentLearnActivity extends Fragment {
/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int mPageNumber;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
 */
public static FragmentLearnActivity create(int pageNumber) {
    FragmentLearnActivity fragment = new FragmentLearnActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public FragmentLearnActivity() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn_activity, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Dummy content. -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/backView"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dolor sit amet"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExample1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExample2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation."
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewExample1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

В `LearnActivity` на строке  `return FragmentLearnActivity.create(position);` получаю ошибку:

```
Error:(55, 13) error: LearnActivity.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method getItem(int) in FragmentStatePagerAdapter
Error:(63, 25) error: getItem(int) in LearnActivity.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter cannot override getItem(int) in FragmentStatePagerAdapter
return type android.app.Fragment is not compatible with android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Error:(58, 19) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Error:(62, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Как ее исправить?

Comment: что вы сами пытались для этого сделать?

Comment: зашtл на офф сайт прочитал туториал, скачал пример, но там поймал ошибку в одном месте.

Comment: такие задачи на freelance.ru надо=)

Comment: Я вот здесь не вижу вообще никаких попыток нажатий на кнопку. Здесь  не делают работу за просто так, здесь могут помочь исправить ошибку или подсказать верное решение.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да ладно, это уже 100500 раз реализовано, ошибка просто где то!

Comment: @pavlofff я не прошу вас решать задачу, тем более что она почти решена, просто этих строчка что то не так public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FragmentLearnActivity.create(position);

Comment: Вопрос решен. Просто где-то какая-то ошибка и что-то где-то не так.  С такими вводными и Ванга бы сдалась вам помогать. ГДЕ САМА ОШИБКА !

Comment: @pavlofff вверху

Comment: всего-то надо было внимательно читать туториал, и использовать фрагменты из `android.support.v4`

Comment: @metalurgus в том то и дело, что в туториале как раз использовалось не support.v4

Comment: То ли вы уже хорошо поработали над этим туториалом (скорее всего копировали код без импортов и они были автодобавлены самой IDE), то ли писал его какой то школьник. Одни только импорты `FragmentActivity` и `AppCompatActivity` при использовании последней заставляют задуматься ..

Comment: @pavlofff в туториале были указаны импорта вроде бы правильно, но я скачал исходники и скопировал "вместе с импортами" - а они на сайте и в иходниках оказались почему то разными, на сайте были support.v4. а в исходниках android.app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ошибке сказано, что класс `Fragment`не совместим с классом `v4.Fragment` и класс `FragmentManager` не может быть преобразован в класс `v4.FragmentManager`.

Вам нужно привести все фрагменты и все, что с ними связано, к одному пакету.
Либо нативным из SDK (`android.app.Fragment` и прочие), либо к библиотеке поддержки *support.v4*(`support.v4.app.Fragment`).

Также, некоторые методы для обращения с классами из библиотеки поддержки отличаются от методов для нативных фрагментов, например для класса `support.v4.FragmentManager` используется метод `getSupportFragmentManager()` вместо `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: в местах где была ошибка - ошибка пропала. но появилась вот такая
Error:(36, 71) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

@pavlofff В строке mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()); 

Я так понимаю ошибка таже, но я пробую привести к support.v4 но почему то не получается

Comment: ВСЁ , что связано с фрагментами, нужно привести к одному пакету(`android.app` или `support.v4.app`), в том числе и класс `FragmentManager`. В импортах активити и фрагмента укажите один из пакетов для всего, другой удалите.

Comment: я в описании добавил импорты, не пойму что именно я упустил.

Comment: @KirillStoianov для класса `support.v4.FragmentManager` используется метод `getSupportFragmentManager()` вместо `getFragmentManager()`