# Не распознается тип фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть класс `WorkoutDetailFragment`, который наследуется от `Fragment`.
В скрипте пытаюсь вернуть ссылку на этот фрагмент, но возникает следующая ошибка:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast android.app.Fragment to com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetail.Fragment

Вот код вызова фрагмента:

```
WorkoutDetailFragment frag =(WorkoutDetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

В чём у меня недочёт?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482351/177345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, вы используете фрагмент из библиотеки поддержки v4.

Попробуйте использовать `getSupportFragmentManager()` вместо обычного.

Comment: Ошибка. Этот метод не известен Android Studio. Я опять забыл какую то библиотеку подключить?

Comment: Обычно просто импорта в проект достаточно (alt+enter на ошибке, он сам предложит). У вас фрагмент от v4 наследуется, посмотрите?

Comment: Да, v4. alt+enter предлагают только сделать метод

Comment: Пардон, getSupportFragmentManager работает. Просто мелкий косяк за мной. Спасибо за помощь